# What steps should I take to recover my data due to partition error?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, paragon

Specs :

- HD : 3 TB external Samsung Hard-disk
- OS : Win 8.1 64 Bit
- SW : Paragon

How it happened :

- Applied a **resize** at end operation in Paragon on my 3 TB disk.  I wanted the 3 TB to split to 2980 GB and 20 GB.
- Paragon started applying.  After about .5 hour, there was an I/O error.  I did not ignore/force close.  I cancelled using the button given  by paragon.
- Checked if External Drive was detected - No
- Rebooted, checked again - not detected
- Right clicked My Computer to check the status of disk - Windows sees it as an un-formatted 3 TB disk with **2300 GB and 700 GB**. (I expected either **2980 GB and 20 GB or 3TB.**)
- Used Test Disk to make sure it **can** read the headers - It can

My plan
- Boot into Ubuntu using LIVE CD and see what Ubunutu sees.
- If it cannot find the disk in proper structure, will download a recovery software and try.

**Request you to suggest** what is the best way forward.  Please help me.

Comment: Ubuntu could not detect the disk.  I think this is because of the corrupt MBR

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
I used testdisk to get my data back.  I analysed my disk, then I wrote the structure back to the disk.  Windows found the MBR and I could see all my files.

**Details**
Drive was not detected because of corrupt MBR which Paragon did.